# Why xemacs looks like this?

Tags: 12.04, fonts, emacs

On a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 xemacs looks like this

[image]

where as emacs looks like this

[image]

Xemacs also produces the following warnings:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with fonts in xemacs under opensuse 12.1. 
It disappeared after I added a different font description (different iso) in my xemacs starting files:
(set-face-font 'default 
                         "-b&h-lucidatypewriter-medium-*-*-*-14-140-*-*-*-*-iso10646-1")

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest solution would be to just use `emacs23` command to run emacs (installed using the standard `emacs23` package). *They are the same program underneath after all.* Actually they are different but they are so similar they might as well be the same thing.

As to why `xemacs` looks so different, it is because it is built using the lucid graphics toolkit which does not use gtk themes or freedesktop icon themes.

Comment: Emacs and XEmacs are definitely *not* the same program. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xemacs

Comment: They are essentially the same. You can probably trade between them with little to no trouble. The only major difference between emacs23-gtk (i.e. emacs) and xemacs is the tools they use to create their windows. emacs23-gtk uses gtk and xemacs does not (apparently using the lucid tool kit).

Comment: Ok thanks for the info about the underlying graphics toolkit. Personnaly, I fell that Xemacs looks like in the seventies ;-) More over I steel have a font problem as reported in the question. Any idea on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Install missing fonts

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
cd /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi
sudo mkfontdir
xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi
```

Make xset permanent

```
echo 'xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi' >>~/.xsessionrc
```

xemacs not emacs... xemacs forked from emacs